# To create only one endpoint which will work for two endpoints

Tags: java, spring-boot, api

Spring -> How to user request parameter in fetch all endpoint?
(If i want to make only one endpoint for fetch all and fetch by Id)

I'm not understanding how to do it in service. I've tried to do it with if-else condition but it's not working because I've passed an argument in service so for fetch all it will not work.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create one API called `/example/fetch` and decide what to return based on `@RequestParam`. take look below reference code.

Add @RequestParam with required attribute as false for non mandatory param.

```
@RequestMapping("/example/fetch")
public List<UserDetail> fetchUsersDetails(@RequestParam(required = false) String userId) {

    if(userId == null || userId.isEmpaty()) {
       // call FetchAll API and return List from DB
    } else {
      // call fetchById API and return List which has only one value if it present in to DB other wise empty list
    }
}
```

Comment: You can up vote as well..If it helps